# Service running in background to post new object but sends multiple times

Tags: android, background-service

I am using a background service to allow users to upload new stamps however when the user closes the app, it redelivers the stamp again to the server, instead of the one time at that is it, therefore making multiple duplicates... how do I avoid it, this is the code I am using:

```
public class UploaderService extends Service {

    /** indicates how to behave if the service is killed */
    int mStartMode;
    /** interface for clients that bind */
    IBinder mBinder;
    /** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
    boolean mAllowRebind;

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final String title;

        Bundle data = null;
        if(intent.getExtras() != null) {
           data = intent.getExtras();

        }

        if(data != null) {
            title = data.getString("title");

            UploadSessionManager uploadSessionManager = new UploadSessionManager(this);
            uploadSessionManager.createUploadSession(title);

        } else {
            UploadSessionManager uploadSessionManager = new UploadSessionManager(this);
            HashMap<String, String> uploadMap = uploadSessionManager.getUserDetails();

            title = uploadMap.get("title");

        }



            ApiManager.getAsyncApi().addStamp(title, new Callback<StampResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(StampResponse stampResponse, Response response) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    UploadSessionManager uploadSessionManager = new UploadSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                    uploadSessionManager.logoutUploadSession();
                    notifyUser("stampDone", stampResponse.get_id());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            });
        }




        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    private void notifyUser(String itemDone, String itemId) {
        Bundle extraData = new Bundle();
        extraData.putString("itemId", itemId);
        extraData.putString("itemDone", itemDone);


        Intent intentWake = new Intent();
        intentWake.putExtras(extraData);
        intentWake.setAction("done");
        intentWake.addCategory("done");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intentWake);

    }


    /** A client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return mAllowRebind;
    }

    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The ApiManager call is sending the data to the server, but when a response is returned I want to stop it completely since it has finished the job, but for some reason it resends the data again because of the Start_redeliver_intent call, not sure how to say the job is finished and not to redeliver it even if the app is closed by the user, which is when it usually resends the data again.

Comment: please elaborate your issue.... cant understand from where data is coming n  which method sends data to server.....

Comment: Ok please  check the update above

Comment: Ok why you are not using flag in your database table which will make Sure that data is already uploaded on server .....